# HDD filesystem turned to RAW after freeze / manual reboot

Tags: hard-drive

i got some unfortunate situation here,
I'm using a dual boot computer ( Ubuntu - win10 ) and while I was transfering / writing data on a NTFS HDD on ubuntu, Ubuntu froze for whatever reason so I got to manually reboot the computer.
After reboot the HDD wasn't seen anymore by Ubuntu, and in windows, it was still seen but as RAW data HDD (still filled with TBs of datas but can't access it )
as it's seen as RAW, no chkdsk command works on it.

would someone have any suggestions of any process that would help recovering the DATA ?

(the HDD is docked in a 4 stairs USB3 external docker, the 3 others HDDs works well)

thanks for your help

Comment: In my experience, questions which scream of improper grammar attract downvotes. Readers might take it as an indication of how little effort was put into asking the queston. Unless you are very very special, asking without putting effort into your question will surely not lead to anywhere useful.

Comment: i is I, no need to put spaces after ( and before ), before ?. No need to thank anyone. Sentences should start with a capital letter, and end with proper punctuation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask <- useful.